# adding correct return statement to function

Tags: java

The answer might be obvious but even after Googling it, I still can find the correct way to solve this problem. I know that I must add a return statement at the very end of the function so that it can complete, but what kind ?

The following program implements an algorithm that find the i-th smallest element in an arrayed-list

```
    public int search(ArrayList<Integer> a, int i){
    ArrayList<Integer> smaller_than = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> greater_than = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int pivot = a.get(i);

    for(int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
        if (a.get(j) <= pivot){
            smaller_than.add(a.get(j));}
        if (a.get(j) > pivot){
            greater_than.add(a.get(j));}}

    if (smaller_than.size() == i)
        return smaller_than.get(i);
    else if (smaller_than.size() < i)
        return search(greater_than, i-smaller_than.size());
    else if (smaller_than.size() > i)
        return search(smaller_than, i);
}
```

I cannot add return null at the end obviously, so can you help me find the solution ?

Comment: Your method has to return an int

Comment: If the missing return statement is just for satisfying the compiler, you can put a return -1; at the end.

Comment: Although I understand what you are trying to achive with you algorithm, I don't understand why you making it this cumbersome. It looks like you implementing first a quicksort. Why don't you just sort the List with `Collections.sort(...)` (which probably does it internally by quicksort) and took the i-th element from it?

Comment: correct, I could have done that, but I'm actually a first year student and that was one of our assignements :)

Comment: Ok. I already guessed something like that =) I just wanted to emphasize the use of Java Util classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just turn the last `if else` to an `else` since if it ain't the same or smaller it must be larger:

```
if (smaller_than.size() == i)
    return smaller_than.get(i);
else if (smaller_than.size() < i)
    return search(greater_than, i-smaller_than.size());
else
    return search(smaller_than, i);
```